# Changing WPF Element Properties with methods

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, properties, wpf-controls

Alrighty, so it took me a long while, but I managed to come up to a better composed question for this. Using `Reflection` I managed to mow it down to this:

```
public void setButton(Button Button, string Content, string ToolTip)
{
    PropertyInfo contentProperty = Button.GetType().GetProperty("Content");
    PropertyInfo toolTipProperty = Button.GetType().GetProperty("ToolTip");
    contentProperty.SetValue(Button, Convert.ChangeType(Content, contentProperty.PropertyType))
    toolTipProperty.SetValue(Button, Convert.ChangeType(ToolTip, contentProperty.PropertyType))
}
```

I've tested this and it works pretty great, but the only issue left is how can I make this same method change the Click event as well?

Comment: Don't worry about runtime efficiency for now. Just get it working, then optimize later if there's a performance problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Nice to see you again Ed, quite a helper you are, aren't ya? Well to be specific here, the problem is not **runtime** efficiency, it's more of management efficiency. Because I would have several events, each with it's own choice, I would need a method to set those up, but I don't know how to change properties of several objects in one method, and at that I have no idea on how to have it set specific properties depending on the "EV000" string that is about to be set on TextBox

Comment: Well, whatever meaning of "efficiency" you're worrying about, stop worrying about it and get your code working first. Based on the questions you're asking here, that is the next step on your shortest path to writing solid, maintainable code for the ages.

Comment: Are you saying that an "Event" has a `Content` property, a `ToolTip` property, a `Click` property, and maybe a `Name` property?

Comment: Second question: What text is changing? This is a TextChanged event. That usually means the user changed some text in a TextBox in the UI. Is that the case here?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Do excuse me for absence, had little errands to run. But to explain it simply, user does not have access to the contents of TextBox as I made it disabled, for that exact purpose. Button.Click is what changes it's text, and I intend to use TextChanged event to change Content, Tooltip and Click properties using that, which in theory would save up on copy-pasting that code over and over. But the issue is getting the values, which I am currently working on figuring out. And as far as Event goes, I simply want the "EV00X" string to also hold properties that should be assigned to buttons

Comment: @EdPlunkett Also just because I ran out of characters to write in previous comment... how can I say, store the equipment that "Player" currently has? I made a Medieval_Sword class which inherits from Weapon class, the Sword class has Medieval_Sword() { //properties' value set here}. And I have public object equippedMeleeWeapon = new Medieval_Sword() for testing purposes, it's not that much related to my question, but it'd prevent me from making one related to that topic

Comment: 'The "EV00X" string` can't hold properties. You can't do it that way. You need to do things in a way that the language actually supports. You can write an `Event` class that has the properties you want. You can have an `Event` named `EV001` that has a `Name` property that returns `"EV001"`, or `"Fred"`, or whatever you want it to say its name is. You can have a collection of those `Event` objects, or whatever. You can give your Window class a property `public Event EV001 { get; } = new Event() { Name = "EV001", Content="Blah blah event something" };` -- or whatever.

Comment: The equipment that the player currently has would probably go in a collection of some kind. `Weapon` should inherit from `Item`; `Bag of Holding` would also inherit from `Item`, etc. etc. Anything that you can pick up and carry is an `Item` of some kind. Then your `Player` class would have a property `public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; }`.

Comment: There are other considerations; maybe after the user kills an animal he can pick it up and carry it around. Do you want to have a `Beaver` class that inherits from `Animal`, but after he kills it, it becomes a `DeadBeaver`, a completely different class that inherits from `Item`? A live beaver and a dead beaver don't functionally have a whole lot in common, when you think about it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah I took the collection in consideration, and have `ObservableCollection<object> Inventory`, and I used object tag because I planned on using `new Medieval_Blade()` sort of way of adding items to inventory, so it exists as an object I can remove, say when player equips it from inventory, it runs code to delete the object inside the inventory after creating copy of it in `public object equippedMeleeWeapon` EDIT: Also I ran into a specific problem. When I do this `public object equippedMeleeWeapon = new Medieval_Weapon()`, it ends up with no properties, what did I do wrong?

Comment: In `ObservableCollection<object>`, '<object>` isn't a "tag". `Object` is the type that's contained in the collection. It's an ObservableCollection *of* Object. That means that you want to restrict the collection to containing only `object`, or classes derived from `object`. That's why `Item` is a better choice, but `object` won't kill you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well to put up a "whole picture", I created an `Item` class, and then `Weapon` and `Armor` classes that inherit from `Item` class, then there's `Medieval_Blade` which inherits from `Weapon` class, it then also has a constructors that assigns values to it. But the problem is same as I added to my last comment, when I do `equippedMeleeWeapon = new Medieval_Sword()`, `equippedMeleeWeapon` ends up with no properties, so I am a bit clueless

Comment: Is `equippedMeleeWeapon` declared as `object`? Since it's meant to be a weapon, declare it as `Weapon`: `public Weapon equippedMeleeWeapon { get; set; }` or whatever. Then a) you can't accidentally assign a `DeadBeaver` to it, and b) you can easily see its `Weapon` properties. You can then find out what it's *real* type is (e.g. `Medieval_Blade`), and *cast* it: `if (equippedMeleeWeapon is Medieval_Blade) { ((Medieval_Blade)equippedMeleeWeapon).SomeMethodOnlyMedieval_BladeHas(); }`

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ohhh I didn't think of that one, pretty obvious solution and I am blind to it as if I had no eyes to begin with. I'll be trying that currently, since I am making this 'game' specifically to learn C#, which of course means **make code until you hit a wall, when you hit it, keep smacking your head against it until you find a way around it**

Comment: The best thing to do is to design `Weapon` so your code doesn't *need* to know the actual type. Say it has a `Weight` property and a `Name` property (they're inherited all the way from `Item`), and a `Damage` property. `Medieval_Blade` has a `Damage` of `5.0`, `Thumbtack` has a `Damage` of `0.3` -- you don't need to know what exact type of `Weapon` it is when the user pokes somebody with it. You tell the user `String.Format("You poke the {0} with your {1} and do {2} points of damage", target.Name, equippedMeleeWeapon.Name, equippedMeleeWeapon.Damage);`

Comment: @EdPlunkett Alright just tested it and I have perfect access to the properties and `Medival_Blade` retains all of it's values. You're a life savior for me here. Still, I have one side-tracked question related to `Weapon` and `Item` I guess. To determine what type of equipment everything is, I use a boolean `isWeapon`, `isUsable` and such. But can I create some sort of "Flag" to add on Items to determine that without a boolean? EDIT: Also about your last comment, that's exactly how I did it, I just had trouble of assigning it to equippedMeleeWeapon properly, which I got around with your help

Comment: `You poke the Dead Beaver with your Tweezers and do 0.01 points of damage`.

Comment: I think at this point `bool IsWeapon`, `bool IsUsable` etc. are fine. You want those to be in the common base class for all in-world objects, which I think is `Item`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah I did that, but it just feels... clumsy. And as side note, is it smart idea to determine say, Player's race, using `public int Race = 1`, so that when the Player's race is requested, it receives a number, which it then uses to determine the 'answer'? I just wish I could just do it like `Human = 1; Elf = 2`. But I guess it'd be smart to do it like `public const int Human = 1` and then when I need name of the race I just do it like `raceLabel.Text = nameof(Human)`? EDIT: I really feel bad for turning this comment section into a discussion, but sadly now I can't access chat

Comment: i'd rather use an enum for that: `public enum Race { Human, Elf, Dwarf, Beaver };`, then in the `Player` class have `public Race Race = Race.Human`. `raceLabel.Text = somePlayer.Race.ToString();` With an `enum` in C# that'll get you the name of the `enum` value, "Human", "Dwarf", whatever. If there's anything to know about races other than their names, you'll eventually want `Race` to be another class. But for now Keep It Simple, and make race just an `enum` value that doesn't really mean anything. Leave the fancy stuff for version 1.1.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah that's great idea. It's just that in my last encounter with `enum`, I had no idea how to use it afterwards. And one question, I just noticed that I can't do things like say, a half breed of a Dragon would be "Dragon-morph", but I can't use "-" in the name, and if I use "_" it'll display it as "Dragon_morph" when using `ToString()`, is there a way around that or do I have to change the naming? Okay now I really feel reeeal bad about turning this into a convo, but it's much more easier to learn when someone skilled explains it to you, more so then reading **MSDN** stuff...

Comment: Just give `Item` a virtual `Name` property: `public virtual String Name { get { return "Item"; } }`. Let every subclass override that property. `Dragon_Morph` would override it as `public override String Name { get { return "Dragon-morph"; } }`

Comment: Self-teaching programming can be very hard. In 1995 I tried to teach myself C and I don't know if I could have done it without my brother helping.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I got what you meant by that virtual property thing... but wouldn't I have to create a separate property for Creature, which Player derives from? And even if so, how do I actually implement it individually for each Race name that needs "fixing"? Can I somehow make a method, or something like that, that would simply replace "_" with "-" instead?

Comment: You could make `Item`'s version do that: `public virtual String Name { get { return GetType().Name.Replace("_", "-"); }`. Then any class that needs to overload it can do so, but the base class version will cover most cases, or even all.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah we have a bit of miscommunication here, I do understand what you are saying. It's just that `Creature` doesn't derive from `Item`, nor does `Player`. So it just means I have to make one inside `Creature` instead. And perhaps before I end up running into the problem again, how would I go around saving the data to a file? Do I use serialization on instances of `Player` or `Events` and such? I am pretty sure that is how I should go around it

Comment: Oh, right, yeah, good point -- so make a common base class for everything, `Creature`, `Item`, and `Player` all derive from it. Call it, uh, `Thing`. Every Thing on earth has a Name. Put the `Name` property there.

Comment: Saving data to a file: Serialization, yeah. You'd have some kind of game environment class that owns all the events, the Player, etc. etc. All the state of the game. Make it serializable to XML and stuff it in a file. Done.

Comment: @EdPlunkett So far I initialized those in the MainWindow.xaml.cs because I need them existing in there to assign them as DataContext to certain WPF elements. But if I could still use them from different classes... how about creating a `public class Storage` that will hold all the created instances? Also just a question about the "Name" thing... how do I **use** it after creating, and what for?

Comment: You use `Name` for whatever you're using `nameof(Dragon_morph)` for now. If your code picks a random Creature to jump out from behind a woodpile, tell the user `String.Format("A random {0} jumped out at you from behind the woodpile.", randomlyChosenCreature.Name);` I don't know what you were using it for, but you said you were doing something where you wanted the underscore to be a hyphen.

Comment: `public class Storage` sounds fine, much better than storing all that stuff in your window class.

Comment: @EdPlunkett So basically it... oh yeah it should 'fix' the string that it gets. But don't I need a `set {}` to be able to change it? I do know I should just have it as read-only, but I need it to be read-write to let the player choose name for themselves. EDIT: Also about what I intend to use it for, I just want it to fix "_" to "-" so that when player's race is displayed it doesn't just show "Dragon_morph"

Comment: Well, further to that thought: All beavers may be named "Beaver", but not all humans are named "Fred". You've got a lot of dragons, say you have two Dragon-morphs, are they both named Dragon-morph? Or are they both members of the Dragon-morph species, and one is named Fred and the other is named Barney? Maybe this readonly `Name` property should be called something else.

Comment: You could just give `Name` a `set`, and `Item` would initialize it in its constructor: `public Item() { Name = GetType().Name.Replace("_", "-"); } public virtual String Name { get; set; }`. Then subclasses can replace it with their own value if they want, or not. Player can change his name to "Kaitlyn" or something.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well first of all, I doubt `Item` would need to have anything corrected from "_" to "-" because their names are a string property anyway, two in fact, one is `shortName` and other is `longName`, short name is the one displayed on a button when player accesses their inventory, so it'd fit. Anyway, the other more on-topic question is, how can I grab say, EV001_A, and then assign it's properties, like `button1.Text = EV001_A.b1Text`. The main problem is how can I do that as a method, while providing only the name of the object, "EV001_A"?

Comment: Well, I don't know where you were getting the name "Dragon_morph" from, but it's not my problem. If you put all your Events in a `Dictionary<String, Event> Events`, you can easily look them up by name. Is this a choose your own adventure thing, or a more free-form D&D kind of thing?

Comment: @EdPlunkett If I were to say the name of the game that this concept is based off, that'd be referring to NSFW content, so I'll refrain from that. But it is mostly like a free-roam with your own choices. And that said "Dragon_morph", it's from `public enum Race { Human, Dragon_morph, Demon }`. The reason why I couldn't use "-" is because it treated it like operator. Oh and the events... while I could do Dictionary, I'd like to still have them in form of a method that sets properties, because I want it to change properties of buttons when it's 'invoked'

Comment: @EdPlunkett And to give better explanation of why I want to do them as methods is this: If I were to have Events as strings, I'd have to do it like `private void Button1_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { textBox.Text = Events.EV001; button1.Content = "Choice 1"; button1 -= Button1_Click; button1 += Button1_Click2;}` which is obviously annoying to do for each choice

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** use events and code-behind in WPF.

**Do** use `Commands` and Data Binding.

I suggest you read some tutorials like at [WPF Tutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) which will introduce you to the concepts you need to make your game painlessly in WPF.

Comment: While I can see why it'd be a smart choice, I fail to see how I can accomplish what I need using those commands. As far as I can see, they execute a line of code, which a method can do as well, along with using variables, fields and such, which commands don't seem to do. Unless there'd be a way of adding a command that would fire off when TextBox's text property changes

Comment: @Zephylir As far as I can tell, "and Data Binding" is in about the same size font as "Commands". Are you having trouble making that out on your screen?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well, if you mean creating a variable to store information that is to be used by UI elements, and then using setting value of those variables inside the commands, sure, it can work I guess. But that'd use just as much figuring out as just doing it in code behind, which I prefer more due to having to use only it and not just going in between XAML and C# to figure out what's wrong

Comment: @Zephylir I guess I'll just have to defer to your superior knowledge and experience.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I really don't mean to offend anyone **or** pretend to know anything about programming. But I just don't see the point of using WPF Commands if I can use Code Behind, since I'd still have to figure out how to do it with Commands anyway. And I would prefer to do it in C# mostly, since it gives more flexibility, for me personally.

Comment: @Zephylir For somebody who doesn't mean to pretend he knows anything about programming, you sure do pretend to know a lot about programming. Anyway, it doesn't matter if you use data binding or not, because anything you write at this level of experience will be a mess in any case. Just write it. The important thing is to just *write* it, as well as you can. That's the only way to learn. I suggest Windows Forms instead of WPF, because Windows Forms is designed to be work with the programming methods you insist on using. Writing WPF that way is crazy. But you're the expert, do whatever.